# Recent actions present perfect continuous

Tags: present-perfect

If I am not mistaken present perfect continuous is correct in these examples. But if the person has already left would it be wrong to use present perfect continuous in A B and C?

1. "So, you are about to leave. How long have you been waiting?"

2."So, are ready to give up. How long have you been waiting?"

3. "So, you're leaving now. How long have you been waiting?"

A "So, you were about to leave when she arrived. How long have you been waiting?"

B "So, you left. How long have you been waiting?"

C "So, you were leaving when she arrived. How long have you been waiting?"

If as native speakers told me using present perfect continuous isn't wrong in such sentences as "she has been studying English for two years, but last week she moved to another school where they don't teach it." And "I would say "I have been living in that house for 20 years even if I moved a few days ago." Said by a native speaker.
So if present perfect continuous works in them does it work in A B and C? To talk about actions that were recent a few days ago or at least last week.

Comment: I would definitely use _had you been waiting_ in A, B and C. The waiting is over in all cases.

Comment: But why in some cases it is possible to use present perfect continuous while in other cases it's not. The person has finished studying,  and in the second sentence he has stopped living in a particular place, in the additional sentences I quoted,  however present perfect continuous isn't wrong in them.

Comment: Well, I would _not_ say "I have been living there" if I had already moved out. Other native speakers evidently think differently. I seem to remember that this issue has been discussed at length before.

Comment: So most native speakers use present perfect continuous if the action has finished but it has to be a recent action and the person must be still present. Right? And the sentences 1, 2, 3 are correct, aren't they?

Comment: Wrong.  I said that I would _not_ use the present perfect continuous if the action had finished.

Comment: I mean the sentences 1 2 3 are correct, aren't they? I thought what applies to my book's example applies to my examples: The book's example: "they have been waiting for an hour. You are here. (The waiting is finished.) The waiting is finished in my three sentences too.

Comment: Yes, 1, 2 and 3 are correct (the person waiting is preparing to leave; they haven't left yet).

Comment: Thank you !